# Angular2 form validation on certain conditions

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, angular, typescript

I have setup a form with form builder and i would like to setup custom validation based on a value change

So this is my form

```
 constructor(){

 this.newtruck  = this._formbuilder.group(
  {
    'trucktype':[''],
    'transporter':[''],
    'dropdown_transporter':[''],
    'truck_number':[''],
    'dropdown_truck_number':[''],
    'driver_name':[''],
    'dropdown_driver_name':[''],
    'driver_number':[''],
    'material':[''],
  }
 )

}
```

On a dropdown change a value is passed to this function

```
updateSelectedValue(item) {

if(item){
  if(item.dropdown == 1) {
    this.newtruck.setControl("dropdown_transporter", new FormControl('', Validators.required));
    this.newtruck.setControl("dropdown_transporter", new FormControl('', Validators.required));
    this.newtruck.setControl("dropdown_driver_name", new FormControl('', Validators.required));

  } else  if(item.dropdown == 0){
     this.newtruck.reset();

    this.newtruck.setControl("transporter", new FormControl('', Validators.required));
    this.newtruck.setControl("truck_number", new FormControl('', Validators.required));
   this.newtruck.setControl("driver_name", new FormControl('', Validators.required));
    this.newtruck.setControl("driver_number", new FormControl('', Validators.required));
}
}
```

}

Now on the form i have a button that i set enbled or disabled by

```
<button ion-button icon-rig color="danger" [disabled]="!newtruck.valid" (click)="onCreate()" > Save
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>

    </button>
```

The above button is always disabled even form is instantiated what could be wrong as you can see at first no validators are called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the condition into the validator by wrapping the validator by your custom validator function.

```
this.newtruck.setControl("dropdown_transporter", 
  new FormControl('', 
    (control:Control) => { 
      if(item && item.dropdown == 1) {
      return Validators.required(control)
      }
    )
  );
```

You can also move out the whole function like

```
updateSelectedValue(item) 

  var requiredValidator = (control:Control) => { 
    if(item && item.dropdown == 1) {
      return Validators.required(control)));
    }
  };

  this.newtruck.setControl("dropdown_transporter", 
    new FormControl('', requiredValidator));
  ...
}
```

Comment: requirecValidator = retuns a syntax error when used inside the updateSelectedValue which is a method inside a class

Comment: I forgot a few characters. Please post the exact error message if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ive seen where the error is its at returnValidators.required there are many closing brackets but your syntax works

Comment: Could you also help me in this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982662/angular2-enable-an-input-field-on-check-of-radio-button