# Angular2 enable an input field on check of radio button

Tags: angular, typescript

Am iterating through items and i would lie to show an input box if a certain radio button is checked

This is the form

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let checklist of checklists;let i=index">

   <input type='radio' name="check{{checklist.id}}" value='yes_{{checklist.id}}'> Yes


   <input type='radio' name="check{{checklist.id}}" value='no_{{checklist.id}}'> Not passed


       <ion-item [hidden]="">//hide when Not passed radio is not checked
         <ion-label floating>Comment</ion-label>
         <ion-input type="text"></ion-input>
       </ion-item>

</ion-card>
```

How do i hide the comment area when no is not checked and show it only when checked

Answer (score 1):

```
   <input #notPassed type='radio' name="check{{checklist.id}}" value='no_{{checklist.id}}'> Not passed


       <ion-item [hidden]="notPassed.value == '...'">//hide when Not passed radio is not checked
```

(I don't know what actual values you are using, therefore just `...`)

Hint: not tested myself yet.

Comment: The value of not passed radio button is determined but the index of  ((*ngFor="let checklist of checklists;let i=index"))  that is the value of i. Ive tried adding  [hidden]="notPassed.value == 'no_{{checklist.id}}" and am getting an error of Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected

Comment: You can't use `[]` and `{{}}` at the same time. Try ` [hidden]="notPassed.value == 'no_' + checklist.id"`

Comment: Okay the error dissapears but the input field always remains hidden even when checked

Comment: When i check on the inspect element the value of the radio doesnt change when checked

Comment: Sorry, don't know about the radio. I haven't ever used one myself.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help how can i also get the values of all checked radio buttons at the end after the iterations so that i can pass the value to a json string

Comment: I guess it's easiest to use a `<form>` element, but with that you have to change quite a bit. In this case I'd suggest you check the forms tutorials at http://angular.io first. When you have a form you can just get all values of the form elements from the form itself.

Comment: Ive changed the implementation to the form way but am now stuck at passing the result of asynchronous call to the form builder. Please check on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987624/angular2-form-builder-with-result-of-asynchronous-call