# Angular2 form builder with result of asynchronous call

Tags: angular, typescript

Am creating my form following a result of an asynchronous call but am stuck at how i should pass the results of the asynchronous calll to the form builder

This is what ive tried

```
export class PerformInspectionPage implements OnInit {
 checklists: any;
 inspectionform: FormGroup;

 ngOnInit(): any {
    this.checklists  = this.onGetItems(); //this is where i fetch the data not sure of
                                        //another way to use.

 let checkinputs: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

 for (let i = 0; i < this.checklists.length; i++) {
   checkinputs.push(
    new FormGroup({
      description:new FormControl(this.checklists[i].item),
      input: new FormControl(''),
      yesradio: new FormControl(''),
      noradio: new FormControl(''),
    })
  )
}

this.inspectionform = this._formBuilder.group({
  inputfileds: this._formBuilder.array(checkinputs.controls)
})

 }
```

Now the function that gets items which is still on the same component

```
 onGetItems(){

    return this._inspectionService.getChecklists()
       .subscribe(
          res=> {
           this.checklists = res;
          },

       );


      }
```

when i check   console.log(this.inspectionform); it has an array of 0 items. How do i modify this to return result an asynchronous call

I have also tried

```
  return this._inspectionService.getChecklists(this.truckParam)
  .subscribe(
    res=> {
      let checkinputs: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

      for (let i = 0; i < this.checklists.length; i++) {
        checkinputs.push(
       new FormGroup({
          description:new FormControl(this.checklists[i].item),
           input: new FormControl(''),
           yesradio: new FormControl(''),
          noradio: new FormControl(''),
        })
     )
    }

    this.inspectionform = this._formBuilder.group({
       inputfileds: this._formBuilder.array(checkinputs.controls)
    })
      },

  );
```

The problem with this is that the instance for formbuilder is never visible on the form

That is

On the form

```
 <form [formGroup]="inspectionform" #newform > //this returns an error of

 formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one
```

Comment: how does `checklist` look like, i.e how does the incoming data look like, might help here to see how the data actually looks like...

Comment: The incoming data is  in json format {id:1, item:"ddhbh",..},{item2},... thats a json array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building the **form MODEL** asynchronously, you also need to display the **form TEMPLATE** asynchronously.

The problem with you current code (the 2nd option you showed) is that Angular tries to display the form BEFORE you have built the model.

Try something like this:

```ts
getChecklists(...)

  .subscribe(() => {

    // Build the form model like you currently do.
    this.inspectionForm = this._formBuilder.group({...});

    // Then, set some kind of flag to indicate that the form is ready.
    this.isFormReady = true;

  });
```

And in the template :

```html
<form *ngIf="isFormReady" [formGroup]="inspectionForm" #newform>
```

In fact, you might just be able to skip the `isFormReady` flag and test the value of the `inspectionForm` property directly:

```html
<form *ngIf="inspectionForm" [formGroup]="inspectionForm" #newform>
```